# Why a Class which implements a Comparable Interface is not Comparable?

Tags: java, generics, multiple-inheritance

To generalize the question

If Interface A is Comparable,
Class B extends Interface A.
And for Class C the type parameter it takes must be comparable.

For class A

```java
public interface A extends Comparable<A>{
}
```

For class B

```java
public class B implements A{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(A o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

For class C

```java
public class C<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public int data;
}
```

Now try to declare an instance of C using the type parameter B

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C<B> test = new C<B>();
    }
}
```

It shows an error

> Type parameter 'B' is not within its bound; should implement 'java.lang.Comparable'

I believe Class B has extended A and should be comparable. I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

For my code:
The relationship between the class and interface is

```java
MovieList implements KeyListInterface
KeyListInterface extends Comparable<KeyListInterface>
```

and the definition of RedBlackTree is

```java
public class RedBlackTree<T extends Comparable<T>> extends BinarySearchTree<T>
```

When I tried to instantiate a RedBlackTree in the test methods with the following line

```java
        RedBlackTree<MovieList> Tree = new RedBlackTree<>();
```

, passing into the type parameter as MovieList, it showed the error

> Type parameter 'MovieList' is not within its bound; should implement 'java.lang.Comparable'

I'm wondering what this error means, since with the structure shown above, I believe that MovieList is comparable

Below is just the placeholder for the MovieList class and the KeyListInterface is shown below

```java
/**
 * This is the interface of a type that will allow us to store duplicate keys in a single node of a tree.
 */
public interface KeyListInterface<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Comparable<KeyListInterface<T>>, Iterable<T> {

    /**
     * Adds another object with the same key to the list.
     * @param newKey new object that maps to the same key as all objects in the list
     */
    public void addKey(T newKey);

    /**
     * Checks if the list contains key.
     * @param key the key object to check for
     */
    public boolean containsKey(T key);

}
```

```java
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MovieList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements KeyListInterface<T> {
    @Override
    public void addKey(T newKey) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(T key) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(KeyListInterface<T> o) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `B` does not implement `Comparable<B>`, so it is not comparable. It is incorrectly defined IMO.

Answer (score 3):

```
MovieList implements KeyListInterface
KeyListInterface extends Comparable<KeyListInterface>
```

Unfortunately, what you have here is that `MovieList` implements `Comparable<KeyListInterface>`, not `MovieList` implements `Comparable<MovieList>`.  This is not a situation where `T implements Comparable<T>` as a result.

You *can* make this work, but to allow it you must modify your generics slightly, with

```
public class MovieList<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, another question is: what if I still want MovieList to implement the KeyListInterface, in this case, how should I deal with the type Parameter passed into the KeyListInterface? Since the code below still shows an error

> Type parameter 'T' is not within its bound; should implement 'java.lang.Comparable<T>'

Comment: You would need to change `KeyListInterface` in the same way.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the instruction, I have tried to modify both the interface and class for MovieList, but the old error still remains. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to make my MovieList both Comparable and also inherit the KeyListInterface.

Comment: Not really.  If you have a new error, show us the updated code and what exact error you get.  It seems likely that you may simply need to find more and more places you need to replace `<T extends Comparable<T>>` with `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`.

Comment: After several attempts, I think it is probably the issue with the Java inheritance. And I have generalized the question a little bit to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Your new edit suggests a completely different issue, likely one where you tried to redefine the `Comparable` interface.  If anywhere in your code has a line that begins `interface Comparable`, that's a problem.

Comment: More to the point, your interfaces work with the correction I've shown: https://ideone.com/BBOsqH